# Does the LockerService make Selenium tests impossible?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, selenium, lightning-testing-service

When running [Lightning Testing Service](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService) tests, the impact of the [LockerService](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm) is evident such as not being able to see the DOM nodes of a `lightning:...` component (different namespace) wrapped by one of my components (including via the JavaScript debugger).

We also want to build [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) UI tests and Selenium tests need to find buttons etc. across the entire DOM. Does the LockerService make Selenium tests impossible?

All details of why or why not appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DOM element encapsulation is applied by Locker Service only during the component's life cycle. In other words, only when a component(controller/renderer/helper) tries to access DOM elements, Locker Service(LS) will apply filtering to restrict access to current component's namespace.

That should not affect Selenium UI tests, both for Selenium webdriver and Selenium RC. Webdriver will be executing outside of the component's lifecycle, like an external entity. LS will not interfere. Similarly, selenium RC javascript will be executing in system mode and will not be restricted by LS.